# Draw A Triangle From 3 Excenters and Ex-radii

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

My teacher gave me this problem and told me to think-

**" Is it possible to draw a triangle, given the three ex-centers and length of the ex-radii?"**

I don't know if it's possible or not. So, my question is-

1. Is it possible?
2. If yes, then how?

Also, he gave me another version where I'm only given the ex-centers, not the ex-radii

Comment: After telling **you** to think, won't your teacher be disappointed that you posted the problem here?

Comment: @Blue He told me to think, which I did......

Comment: If you tell us how far you got in your thinking, we might be able to help you finish thinking (and we won't waste your time, or ours, explaining things that you already know). Help us help you.

Comment: ... sure you don't mean exradii if there are 3 excentres?

Comment: @Benedict Thanks for noticing. Updated the question.

Comment: @Blue I thought of using the fact that If the circle is tangent to side $a$ of the triangle, the radius is $\frac{K}{s-a}$, where $K$ is the triangle's area, and $s = \frac{a+b+c}{2}$. Also, I tried to use the length of the parts of a side when a excircle touches that side. But I got nothing

Comment: @AniketBhattacharyea: You can actually tackle this a bit more conceptually. Take the "hard" version of the problem, where we only know excenters, $X$, $Y$, $Z$. The vertices of the target triangle, say $\triangle ABC$, must lie on the sides of $\triangle XYZ$ (why?), with $A$ on $\overline{YZ}$, etc. Consider the bisector of $\angle A$ in $\triangle ABC$: What is that bisector's relationship with $\overline{YZ}$? What's its relationship with $X$? What do both of those relationships tell you about $A$?

Comment: @Blue Will the bisector of an angle of the target triangle passes through the opposite excenter?

Comment: @AniketBhattacharyea: You tell me. :)

Comment: @Blue my gut feeling says it does. And if it's true (and if I'm not wrong) I think the foot points of the heights of the triangle got by joining the excenters are the vertices of the required triangle

Comment: @Blue yes it does.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found it

[image]

We are to find $\triangle PQR$. As @Blue said, $A,R,P$ are collinear. Similarly $A,Q,C$ and $C,P,B$ are collinear.

Note that, $RA$ is the external bisector of $\angle PRQ$ and $RH$ is the internal bisector of $\angle PRQ$. Hence they're perpendicular.

Now, $R$ and $H$ lies on the internal bisector. $C$ is an $excenter$, which is equidistant from the extension of $RQ$ and $RP$, which are the two sides of $\angle PRQ$. Hence $C$ lies on the internal bisector of $\angle PRQ$. So $R,H,C$ are collinear, and thus $CR$ is the height of $\triangle ABC$.

Thus follows my construction-

Given the excenters $A,B,C$, draw the triangle $ABC$. Drop perpendiculars from the vertices. The foot points of the perpendiculars are the 3 vertices of the required triangle.

Did I do it right?

Comment: @Blue there aren't any flaws, are there?

Comment: The argument is valid, but you don't need to discuss incenter $H$. (What you say about $H$ is true, but unnecessary.) You can simply argue: (1) $C$, being an excenter, is equidistant from the sides of $\angle PRQ$, so that (2) $\overline{RC}$ is an internal angle bisector of $\triangle PRQ$, which implies (3) $\overline{RC}\perp\overline{AB}$ since $\overline{AB}$ is the external angle bisector at $R$; thus, your construction works. Done. (Depending upon how sophisticated your "audience" is, you might want to explain why internal and external bisectors are perpendicular.)